# How to display parent term name of a term located in a paragraph?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, paragraphs

I have a vocabulary for employees, which has a paragraph field. In this paragraph entity, I have two fields. One for date and one for the job title. The hierarchy goes like: company > department > job title. I've created a view where I list all employees and what I want to accomplish is not to show what their job title is. I want to display in which department they work.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

1st you have to make relation with the field who reference to taxonomies after that youhave  to make another relation with your paragraph field to get the job title